# Wie vermeidet man das Wort »Führerin«?

Tags: word-usage, english-to-german

In den USA beschreiben wir Angela Merkel oft als »The Leader of the Free World.«
Als Nichtmuttersprachler fällt es mir schwer, den Ausdruck adäquat zu übersetzen.

Was würde ein deutscher Muttersprachler auf Deutsch sagen?

Comment: Nicht geeignet für eine Antwort, aber interessanter Vergleich: Suche "Führer" und "Duce" (Mussolinis "Titel") in Google, vergleiche Prozentsatz der Fundstellen, die sich auf Person oder Begriff beziehen. Mache dasselbe im deutschen und italienischen Google (Umstellung der Antwortsprache). In beiden Fällen ergibt sich bei mir, dass eine heimatsprachliche Suche grob 50:50 Person und Begriff findet, eine fremdsprachliche annähernd 100% Person.

Answer (score 15):

Wenn du das Wort *leader* ins Deutsche übersetzen willst, hast du zwei Möglichkeiten:

- Führer
- Anführer

Auf Deutsch haben die Wörter *Führer* und *Reich* nicht diese Nazi-Konnotation, die diese Wörter in einem englischen Kontext haben. Denn in einem englischsprachigen Kontext werden diese deutschen Fremdwörter praktisch ausschließlich in Bezug auf Nazis verwendet. In einem Deutschen Kontext sind das ganz normale Wörter. Frank*reich* und Öster*reich* sind nach wie vor Reiche, und niemand denkt sich etwas dabei.

Beim *Führer* ist es ähnlich. Der Leiter einer Pfadfindergruppe heißt auch *Führer* (zumindest war das noch in den 1970er-Jahren so, als ich selbst Pfadfinder war), und bei den Pfadfindern gibt es meines Wissens nicht signifikant mehr Nazis als sonst wo.

> Die Führerin der freien Welt

klingt auf Deutsch also weit weniger dramatisch als das von englischen Muttersprachler wahrgenommen wird. Aber es stimmt schon: Die Nazi-Konnotation ist da, auch im Deutschen, wenn auch nicht so stark ausgeprägt. Und gerade beim Regierungsoberhaupt ist das natürlich problematisch. Daher würde ich das übersetzen als:

> Die Anführerin der freien Welt.

Denn hier klingt zumindest für deutsche Muttersprachler gar kein Nazi-Unterton mehr durch. Allerdings kann ich nicht beurteilen, wie dieser Deutsche Titel auf englische Muttersprachler wirkt.

Weitere Alternativen wären:

> - Die Chefin der freien Welt (the boss of the free world)
> - Die Leitfigur der freien Welt (the leading figure of the free world)
> - Das Oberhaupt der freien Welt (the head of the free world)

---

Übrigens:
Die Vereinigten Staaten werden auf Deutsch mit *USA* abgekürzt und im Plural verwendet:

> In den USA beschreiben wir ...

Comment: _Obiter dictum_: Bei den Pfadfindern wird mittlerweile oftmals _Leiter_ statt _Führer_ verwendet, aber nicht durchgängig. Dafür ist der _Feldmeister_ fast vollständig verschwunden.

Comment: Schöne Erklärung, dass *Führer* in einem fremdsprachlichen Kontext sofort in eine bestimmte Schublade fällt, in die es in einem rein deutschen eben nicht fallen würde. Siehe *Führerschein*, *Kranführer*, *Zugführer*, ... Trotzdem (oder deswegen) nehmen deutsche Nachrichten ungerne *Führer* für einen politischen Kontext, sondern schreiben stattdessen lieber wenigstens *Anführer*. Ich persönlich weigere mich ein bisschen gegen eine solche Praxis, denn das arme Wort kann ja nix dafür.

Comment: Die Konnotation Führer -> Nazis ist zwar schwächer als im Englischen, aber sie existiert ganz eindeutig. "Führer" wird deshalb fast immer durch "Anführer" ersetzt. Bei "Führerin" *könnte* das weniger akut sein, aber ich würde auch dieses Wort normalerweise meiden.

Comment: Danke vielmals! Wie mein letzter Professor der deutschen Sprache schrieb: "Ich sehe, dass dir endlich das Deutsch der  Hoch   Schule ausgegangen ist. D +"  (I see you finally ran out of high school German.  D+)

Comment: @MichaelOwenSartin: Avoid false friends: high school ≠ Hochschule (*Hoch Schule* is just wrong). This is correct: high school = Oberstufe. university = Hochschule (*Hochschule* is a synonym for *Universität*)

Answer (score 5):

#### Leader of the free world

Wir kennen die seit den siebziger Jahren verbreitete Wendung "Leader of the Free World". Diese Rolle einer weltanführenden Nation wurde seit damals in der westlichen Welt den Vereinigten Staaten von Amerika zugesprochen.

Sobald man diesen Titel in Zusammenhang mit einer einzelnen Person nennt, die auch noch eine deutsche Bundeskanzlerin ist, kann das nicht ohne eine ironische bzw. auch sarkastische Konnotation sein. Allein schon deshalb verbietet sich eine Übersetzung, die unmittelbar jegliche solche Konnotation zunichte machte.

Der Begriff wird in Deutschland niemals ernsthaft und ohne Satire in Zusammenhang mit einer Person gebracht. Das läuft unserem Demokratieverständnis zuwider.

Folgerichtig wird in Berichten über eine Nennung von *Leader Of The Free World* zusammen mit Frau Merkel meist **auf eine Übersetzung verzichtet**, zumal man diese Wendung bei politisch halbwegs gebildeten Bürgern als bekannt voraussetzen darf.

> - Britische und US-amerikanische Zeitungen sahen Merkel nun gefordert als "leader of the free world" (Anführerin der freien Welt). <sup>[Süddeutsche](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/politik/merkels-spitznamen-von-kohls-maedchen-zur-ewigen-kanzlerin-1.3904881-2)</sup>
> - Und sie kann auch mit dem Titel nicht viel anfangen, den die "New York Times" ihr unlängst verliehen hat – "Leader of the free world".  Nicht, dass er sie sonderlich bedrückt. Sie hält ihn schlicht für irrelevant. <sup>[Stern](https://www.stern.de/politik/ausland/angela-merkel-in-argentinien--fussball-traeumerei-und-uckermaerkischer-witz-7489290.html)</sup>
> - Ihr seid jetzt die "leader of the free world", bekommt ein Deutscher in den USA derzeit oft zu hören. Es ist ernster gemeint, als uns lieb sein kann. <sup>[Rheinische Post](https://rp-online.de/politik/deutschland/schafft-merkel-es-noch-mal_aid-17869593)</sup>

---

#### Eine führende Rolle spielen

Wenn man außerhalb des oben genannten Kontexts ganz allgemein eine Übersetzung für *leader* sucht, die unverfänglicher ist als *Führer*, greift man gerne auf den *[Anführer](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Anf%C3%BChrer)* zurück, oder umschreibt noch besser den Begriff mit "eine führende Rolle spielen":

> - Im Gegensatz zu anderen Demokratien wie Großbritannien und der USA, deren Ziele in der Klimapolitik von der Redaktion eher kritisch betrachtet würden, sei Merkels Politik fortschrittlich, forschungsfreundlich und ein Grund für Deutschlands **führende Rolle** als Wissenschaftsnation, schreibt die Redaktion.<sup>[Die Zeit](https://www.zeit.de/wissen/2017-09/wahlkampf-angela-merkel-nature-amtszeit-wissenschaft)</sup>

So wird auch "Leader Of The World" im Zusammenhang mit den USA gelegentlich so übersetzt:

> - Die USA schotteten sich nicht ab, sondern hiessen Investitionen und qualifizierte legale Einwanderer willkommen. Sie wollten weiterhin eine **führende Rolle in der Welt** spielen. <sup>[NZZ](https://www.nzz.ch/meinung/die-usa-sollten-nicht-unterschaetzt-werden-ld.1351678)</sup>

Nur selten kann man sie auch im Zusammenhang mit einem Amt hören:

> - Die Deutschen jedenfalls sind mehrheitlich der Meinung, dass Merkel eine **führende Rolle** in der Politik behalten soll.<sup>[Abendblatt](https://www.abendblatt.de/politik/article212635917/40-Prozent-lehnen-weitere-Kanzlerkandidatur-Merkels-ab.html)</sup>
> - Es handle sich um eine "ernsthafte Kandidatur", sagte die 41-Jährige am Dienstag dem Portal "Tagesschau24". Sie fühle sich dazu "berufen, in der SPD eine **führende Rolle** zu spielen an dieser Stelle". Sie habe 15 Jahre Erfahrung in der Partei. <sup>[Die Zeit](https://www.zeit.de/news/2018-02/13/deutschland-flensburger-oberbuergermeisterin-lange-will-in-spd-fuehrende-rolle-spielen-13140202)</sup>

---

<sub>**1. Anmerkung:** es gibt noch die Führungsrolle in einem Betrieb und den Anführer von diversen anderen Gruppen (Pfadfinder, Sport, Verbrecherbanden). Auf eine nähere Ausführung wird hier verzichtet, weil diese Beispiele viel zu weit von dem in der Frage angerissenen Thema sind.</sub>
<sub>**2. Anmerkung:** die vielen versteckten Links im Text führen oft zu Artikeln, die ein wenig Hintergrund zum Thema liefern und zu empfehlen sind.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Anführerin (wenn man von Führungsrollen spricht).

Führer/Führerin wird nur noch für Fahrzeuge oder für Scouts verwendet, politisch jedoch nicht mehr aus bekannten geschichtlichen Gründen.